# Apply different transformations for each element in the stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a class `Node`

```
public class Node {
    private String name;
    private List<Integer> list;
    
    // constructor, getters, etc.
}
```

I want to join `Stream<Node>` into a single `Node` so that I apply different aggregation for the `name` and the `list`. In my case, I want to concatenate all names and flatten all lists.

Example

*Input:*

```
nodes = [
    { Node(name="a", list=[1,2]) },
    { Node(name="b", list=[3,4]) }
]
```

*Output:*

```
result = { Node(name="ab", list=[1,2,3,4]) }
```

How can I do this with streams?

```
List<Node> nodes = getMyNodes();
nodes.stream().????
```

I know that I can use `flatMap()` to flatten lists and that I can use `Collectors.joining()` to join strings, but I don't know how to apply two different transformations on the same stream.

Comment: and here are some tutorial for stream https://dev.java/learn/the-stream-api/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [`Collectors.teeing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#teeing(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.BiFunction))

You can achieve this by using Java 12 Collector `teeing()`, which expects three arguments: two *downstream Collectors* and a `merger` *Function* combining the results produced by these Collectors.

As downstream Collectors, we can make use of:

- A combination of Collectors [`mapping()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) and [`joining()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining()) to join the `name` properties;
- And to in order to group lists Collector [`flatMapping()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#flatMapping(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) in conjunction with `toList()`.

As the merger function, we can a reference to the all-arguments constructor of the `Node`.

```
List<Node> nodes = getMyNodes();
        
Node aggregatedNode = nodes.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.teeing(
        Collectors.mapping(Node1::getName, Collectors.joining()),
        Collectors.flatMapping(node -> node.getList().stream(), Collectors.toList()),
        Node::new // method reference to the all-args constructor
    ));
```

## Mutable Reduction

An alternative option would be to perform mutable reduction of the stream elements using by making use of `collect()` operation and a custom accumulation type.

That's how such accumulation type can be implemented:

```
public class NodeJoiner implements Consumer<Node> {
    private StringBuilder names = new StringBuilder();
    private List<Integer> lists = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void accept(Node node) {
        update(node.getName(), node.getList());
    }
    
    public NodeJoiner merge(NodeJoiner other) {
        update(other.names, other.lists);
        return this;
    }
    
    private void update(CharSequence name, List<Integer> list) {
        names.append(name);
        lists.addAll(list);
    }
    
    public Node toNode() {
        return new Node(names.toString(), lists);
    }
}
```

And the stream would look like this:

```
List<Node> nodes = getMyNodes();
    
Node aggregatedNode = nodes.stream()
    .collect(Collector.of(
        NodeJoiner::new,
        NodeJoiner::accept,
        NodeJoiner::merge,
        NodeJoiner::toNode
    ));
```

## Note

There might be a temptation to use `reduce()` to perform mutable reduction, but it's not a use-case for `reduce()` since this operation is meant to fold a stream by producing a new object at each step of folding (*in other words, perform immutable reduction*).

And [Stream API documentation - Mutable reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction) warns against such usage of `reduce()`:

> A mutable reduction operation accumulates input elements into a
> mutable result container, such as a `Collection` or `StringBuilder`, as it
> processes the elements in the stream.
>
> If we wanted to take a stream of strings and concatenate them into a
> single long string, we could achieve this with ordinary reduction:
>
> ```
> String concatenated = strings.reduce("", String::concat)
> ```
>
> We would get the desired result, and it would even work in parallel.
> However, we might not be happy about the performance! Such an
> implementation would do a great deal of string copying, and the run
> time would be **O(n^2)** in the number of characters. A more performant
> approach would be to accumulate the results into a `StringBuilder`,
> which is a mutable container for accumulating strings. We can use the
> same technique to parallelize mutable reduction as we do with ordinary
> reduction.
>
> The **mutable reduction operation is called** `collect()`, as it collects
> together the desired results into a result container such as a
> `Collection`.

The stream in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74828270/17949945) resembles the above code from the documentation, illustrating a not-recommended way of utilizing `reduce`.

The [answer by @azro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74828310/17949945) is an example of ***correct*** usage of `reduce`, a new object gets created at each step of folding the stream (but since we can accomplish the same using mutable objects, it would be performance wise to replace `reduce()` with `collect()`).

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for reduce operaiton. Check the below code.

```
List<Node> list = Arrays.asList(new Node("a", Arrays.asList(1, 2)), new Node("b", Arrays.asList(3, 4)));

Node finalNode = new Node("", new ArrayList<>());
Node result = list.stream().reduce(finalNode, (finalResult, currentNode) -> {

    finalResult.name = finalResult.name + currentNode.name;

    finalResult.list.addAll(currentNode.list);
    return finalResult;

});
```

Comment: It's worth to note that this approach has quadratic Time complexity **O(n^2)** because it relies on the string-concatenation to merge `name` property.

Answer (score 1):

You can merge 2 nodes again and again, until you get one, that is called reducing

```
List<Node> nodes = Arrays.asList(
        new Node("a", Arrays.asList(1, 2)),
        new Node("b", Arrays.asList(3, 4)),
        new Node("c", Arrays.asList(5, 6))
);
Node result = nodes.stream().reduce(new Node(""), Node::merge);
System.out.println(result);
// Node{name='abc', list=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}
```

```java
class Node {
    String name;
    List<Integer> list;
    public Node() {
        this("");
    }
    public Node(String name) {
        this(name, new ArrayList<>());
    }
    public Node(String name, List<Integer> list) {
        this.name = name;
        this.list = list;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Node{" + "name='" + name + '\'' + ", list=" + list + '}';
    }
    public Node merge(Node other) {
        Node n = new Node(name + other.name);
        n.list.addAll(this.list);
        n.list.addAll(other.list);
        return n;
    }
}
```